# Designing custom adressable RGB PCB

Tags: pcb-design, components

I want to design a custom PCB to connect to my addressable RGB motherboard.
My question is, I have researched the WS2812B led, which seems to be capable of addressable RGB connection.
Would it suffice to just connect an addressable RGB header with decoupling capacitors on the VCC and connect the D pin to Din, and the Dout of the led to the next Din and so on?
Or am I missing something.
And if people have a suggestion for maybe a better/easier design, let me know.

*edit for clarification:
link to led I found:
https://www.seeedstudio.com/document/pdf/WS2812B%20Datasheet.pdf
link to addressable RGB: https://www.msi.com/blog/top-5-accessories-for-rgb-gaming-pc-build-guide
An RGB connector sends as far as I understand 5V to power the leds, and D signal for the colors and brightness.

*edit after some more research:
I found a picture of the ledstrips which use the WS2812B led.
[image: WS2812B led strip]

*update 1:
I made the first prototype and found out (if I had read the datasheet a little bit more closely) that the data send to the leds, is only for 3 leds chained together. So I adjusted my design and will post an update in a few weeks if it works (with pictures).

Comment: Most likely, their LED strip is just a bunch of WS2812B's, so you can also make your own strip of WS2812B's. However, unless you find something that *says so*, we can't assume that.

Comment: as far as I have found online the addressable RGB strips made by different companies use WS2812B, but I have no idea if they connect it in a different way or if there are some resistors or anything on the data lines. The most likely thing to do is just to make a testsetup with 3 leds and connect it to the header. If it works I know enough.

Comment: Your update doesn't seem to make sense.  The chip will take the first three words to control it's three channels then pass on whatever follows which can be used to control the next in the chain.

Comment: @ChrisStratton page 4 on this simplified datasheet suggests my update is correct https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf

Comment: There's no implication there that affects the board design - anything you think does is a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WS2812B LED strips contain just the WS2812 LED/chip packages, with one capacitor (no marking on it, the datasheet will probably have a recommendation) per chip. Ground and +5V go to all chips, data pins daisy-chained (Dout of chip 1 connects to Din of chip2, et)c.

With large amount of chips, separate (parallel) thicker wires are use for GND and +5V.

Comment: I found a picture of a ledstrip that uses the WS2812B led -added to my question- and seems you were right and my understanding was good. Thanks.